# How to pass values to array in react native

Tags: android, arrays, react-native

I am a noob. I am developing a react native app. In that, I have a collection of URLs inside this

> 'this.props.navigation.state.params.PassedURL'

I want to pass all the URLs inside that to the following array.

```
imagess: [{
       url: '',
         }],
```

this is because I am using a package 'react-native-image-zoom-viewer' which only supports this type of array, like this.

```
  <ImageViewer imageUrls={imagess}/></View>
```

how can we this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Push data in the array

```
   var images = []; --create an array--
    var imageUrl = 'https://myimageurl.com'; --define your image url--
    var tempData = '{url:'+ imageUrl +'}'; --create data to be pushed in array--
    images.push(tempData) -- Push the data to array--
```

Now you have collection of urls so put them one by one using loop

```
    var images = [];
    for(i=0; i< url.object.length; i++);
    var imageUrl = url.object.length[0].url;
    var tempData = '{url:'+ imageUrl +'}';
    images.push(tempData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the url like this

```
<ImageViewer imageUrls={imagess[0].url}/></View>
```